# WCF Rest service - Web get method not getting called

Tags: wcf

Url - http://`localhost`:8000/MyFirstRestService works fine
but http://`localhost`:8000/MyFirstRestService?tag=zx doesnt work.

Not sure what did i miss. Please advice

Contract:

```
namespace WcfRESTService
{
[ServiceContract]
public class BookmarkService
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "?tag={tag}")]
    [OperationContract]
    string GetPublicBookmarks(string tag)
    {
        if (tag.Equals("Test1"))
        {               
            return "true";
        }
        else
        {
           return "false";
        }

    }
```

main function

```
        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8000/MyFirstRestService");
        ServiceHost sHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(BookmarkService), baseAddress);
        sHost.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Service Started");
```

config file :

```
<service name="WcfRESTService.BookmarkService" behaviorConfiguration ="RestServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfRESTService.BookmarkService" behaviorConfiguration="webHttp">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>


<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name ="RestServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttp">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

Comment: Woks if i add a / in my weburi template on top of service method like  [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/?tag={tag}")].  However if i add this '/' at the end of base url in the main method and not on uritemplate does not work. What could be the reason?